# Django - How to update views based on dropdown selection from frontend?

Tags: python, django

I want on frontend when a user selects an item from drop down list, a kind of signal is sent to Django backend with the primary-key of the item selected.

Models.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

I send this model to HTML and unpack it:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
</head>

<body>
   <form action="" method="GET" id="selection-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <select>
            {% for company in company_list %}
        <option>
            {{ company.name }}
        </option>
            {% endfor %}
    </select>
     <input type="button" value="Update" id="selection-button">
     </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Now the user selects the option e.g. Company A, Company B and Company C. If the user selects say Company A and click the 'Update' button, it sends the primary-key to views.py

Views.py:

```
def company_selected(request):
    if request.method === 'GET':
        selection = request.GET.get() // Not sure what to have within .get()
        selected_company = Company.objects.filter(pk=selection)
        return selected_company
```

I'm actually not sure if I'm doing it correctly in views.py or not. What kind of signal is sent from front-end that can help to identify the primary-key of the option selected?

Comment: If you want the form to update when an element is selected (i.e. without submitting the form as a whole), you'll need to use AJAX.

Comment: Also, there is no `===` in Python. But the is the `is` operator.

Answer (score 4):

you need to modify your html a liitle to add an `id` to the `select`.

.html

```
<select id = "company-list">
   {% for company in company_list %}
     <option value="{{ company.id }}">
       {{ company.name }}
     </option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

when the button is clicked you can use `.click` function to send an `ajax` call to your view.so modify you .js file like this:

```
// ajax call on your button click
var url = $( '#selection-form' ).attr( 'action' );
$("selection-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: { 
            id: $('#company-list').val();, 
            },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('ok');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

and finally, in the view you can use it like this
views.py

```
def company_selected(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        selection = request.GET.get('id',None) 
        if selection:
            selected_company = Company.objects.filter(pk=selection)
            return selected_company
        else:
            return  #anything you want to send when no id value is sent in the ajax call
```